# Formatting Nokogiri output with Spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, spreadsheet

**What I need**

Is it possible to format Nokogiri output before sending it to a Spreadsheet like Excel?

**Example:**
The table at http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications is formatted nicely, can similar formatting be applied to Nokogiri output using the spreadsheet gem?

**My code**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications"))

#Grab our product specifications
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec li')

#Modify our data
lines = data.map(&:text).join("\n")

#Create the Spreadsheet
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.name = 'My First Worksheet'

#Output our data  to the Spreadsheet
sheet1[0,0] = lines
book.write 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/output.xls'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code create a spreadsheet with a single row, which has a single column.  That column is the concatenation of all of the lines.

To put each of the lines into its own column, then:

```
lines = data.map(&:text)
...
lines.each.with_index do |line, i|                                                        |
  sheet1[0, i] = line                                                                     |
end                                                                                       |
book.write '/tmp/output.xls'                                                              |
```

To put each of the lines into its own row, then:

```
lines = data.map(&:text)
...
lines.each.with_index do |line, i|                                                        |
  sheet1[i, 0] = line                                                                     |
end                                                                                       |
book.write '/tmp/output.xls'                                                              |
```

Comment: Simple and Eloquent :) Thank you.